To evaluate : $\lim\limits_{a \to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{a} \sin(x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x}{\int_{0}^{a} \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x}$
We have to evaluate the limit  $$L=\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{a} \sin x^2  \, \mathrm{d}x}{\int_{0}^{a} \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x}$$
Now, if we try to evaluate using L.Hôpital's rule (with help of Lagrange's), it gives us the limit $1$. But if we try in the following process it gives us the limit $0$. Please check!
$$\begin{align*}
|\sin x^2|\leq 1 
\implies \left| \lim_{a \to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{a} \sin x^2  \, \mathrm{d}x}{\int_{0}^{a} \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x}\right|
&\leq \lim_{a \to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{a}   \, \mathrm{d}x}{\int_{0}^{a} \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x} \\
&=\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{a}{\int_{0}^{a} \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x} \tag{1}
\end{align*}$$
Now since we can write
$$
0\leq \int_{0}^{a} \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x 
\leq \int_{0}^{a} e^{2(x+1)}\, \mathrm{d}x \in R; \; \forall a>0$$
Now we can say , the R.H.S. of eq.$(1)$ converges to $0$. Therefore $|L|\leq 0$.
Now by Sandwich Lemma we can say $L \to 0$ as $a \to 0$.
Now my question is what is wrong in the procedure? Please help. Thank you.

Your estimate goes in the wrong direction. You would need a lower bound on the integral with the logarithm (the fraction gets smaller if the denominator gets larger).

I understand,  I am trying to show that the denominator is neither infinitely large  nor small  , we can bound that limit ... thus if the numerator tends to 0 it causes no problem.

I do not understand what you meant in your last comment. In any case, you claim that you can show that the RHS of $(1)$ goes to zero using your upper bound on the integral of the logarithm. How exactly do you think you can do that?

Both the numerator and the denominator clearly go to zero. It is a matter of whether one is faster than the other (and by how much). My first impression is that your estimate of the sine is too crude.

I'm not sure how valid this is but could you not use the series expansions to get approximations for the two integrals, in which case you get $$\lim_{a\to0}\frac{\frac13a^3+\cdots}{\frac13a^3+\cdots}=1$$

The problem with your method is in using the inequality
$$
\ln^2(1+x) \le e^{2(1+x)}
$$
and hence
$$
\int_0^a\ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x \le \int_0^ae^{2(1+x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
While this inequality is true, bear in mind that your integral of concern lies in the denominator. Hence, to make the quantity
$$
\frac{a}{\int_{0}^{a} \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x}
$$
bigger (i.e. establish an upper bound), you need to make the denominator smaller (i.e. give it a lower bound). That is,
$$
p < q \iff \frac 1 p > \frac 1 q \text{ for } p,q > 0
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{a}{\int_0^a\ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x} \ge \frac{a}{\int_0^ae^{2(1+x)} \, \mathrm{d}x}
$$
the opposite of what you want!

That said, much as noted by Jyrki in the comments, the estimate given for $\sin x^2$ is too crude. Notice the graph of the function you're trying to bound at the end:

You'll need a tighter estimate. For instance,
$$
|\sin \theta| \le \theta
$$
gives you instead
$$
\left| \frac{\int_0^a \sin x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^a \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x} \right|
\le \frac{\int_0^a x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x}{\int_0^a \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x}
= \frac{\frac 1 3 a^3 }{\int_0^a \ln^2(1+x) \, \mathrm{d}x}
$$
This one works much better and gets no inherent contradiction, as hinted by the graph:

